# How to set a formula in a cell using query

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have this query code that I need an App Script to automatically populate on A1 cell using a defined variables, but I am not sure on how to do it,

```
=IFERROR(query(IMPORTRANGE("123456789","'sheet'!A2:I"), " select * where Col6 = 'name' label Col1 'Assigned Date'",1),"")
```

Here is the line of code, how can I set a formula using this.

```
ss.getRange (1,1).setFormula (code here);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

final answer goes here:

```
var contentID = "123456789";
var cName = sht.Range(1,1).getValue();

    var formula4 = "=IFERROR(QUERY(IMPORTRANGE(\""+ contentID + "\",\"'Detail\'!A2:N\"), \" select * where Col1 = \'"+ cName +"\'\",1),\"\")";
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to escape the single quotes.

```
function yourFunc() {
//some code
var formula = '=IFERROR(query(IMPORTRANGE("123456789","\'sheet\'!A2:I"), " select * where Col6 = \'name\' label Col1 \'Assigned Date\'",1))'
ss.getRange(1,1).setFormula(formula);
//...
}
```

Comment: I am trying now to incorporate it with my codes:

var formula = '=IFERROR(QUERY(IMPORTRANGE('+ shtClientID + ',"\'SEO Deliverables Template\'!A2:I"), " select * where Col6 = \'+ cName +\' label Col1 \'Assigned Date\'",1))'

what was wrong in my code? added shtClientID it's a string of the id and the CName a string for the client Name

Comment: In that case the string should like something like this: '=IFERROR(QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("' + shtClientID + '","\'SEO Deliverables Template\'!A2:I"), "select * where Col6 = '+ "'" + cName +  "'"+ ' label Col1 \'Assigned Date\'",1))'